# Can't run any docker commands - timeout

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am sure that this is probably extremely stupid, and I am probably overlooking something, but I cannot run the docker command. For example when I run

```
docker info
```

I get (replaced some numbers with x)

```
Get https://192.16x.5x.1x3:2376/v1.15/version: dial tcp 192.1x8.59.x03x2376: i/o timeout
```

Comment: FYI: If you use boot2docker the IP is almost always `192.168.59.103`. No need to redact it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker machine gets timeout when we switch between wifi-networks/VPN.
If we switch back to the same network where docker container was initiated, we can get back the docker-machine to running state.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer fixed the issue